# Use android-maps-utils in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I am trying to use this library [1] in an Android project either with Android Studio or with ADT. But it doesn't work at all. In ADT I don't know how to handle gradle stuff and in Android Studio, when I try to "Import Project", I get the error "Could not find com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36.

(don't have enough reputation to post picture, it's on imgur with xswZ3.jpg)

I am not familiar with gradle and I only have a vague idea of what it does but all I want is to use something like BubbleIconFactory f = new BubbleIconFactory(this) in my own project.

Any help is appreciated!

[1] https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps your problem is needing the `repositories` outside of the `buildscript` block.

The `repositories` internal to the `buildscript` is for managing the gradle dependency itself, I believe.  Here's how I resolved my problem with `google-maps-utils` as a library dependency.  Hopefully this helps.  I included my maps and support-v4 libs too.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // Support Libraries
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.1.32'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.36` can be downloaded by going to your SDK Manager and installing the `Extras->Google Repository` package (you may want to install the `Extras->Android Support` Repository as well while you are there). These allow Gradle to automatically use these resources without the need for library projects or jars manually added to your project.

Comment: Applying your advice helped through the dialogue producing the error. But afterwards I still got all kinds of errors. Eclipse also began producing many errors. I deinstalled everything related to java / android development and reinstalled only ADT. I removed the strange library from my project and after hours of work I got my project working again (sadly, without the desired library of course). It's irritating what huge potential for errors Eclipse/Java/Android has!

I am going to open a new question about integrating android-maps-utils into an own project using a fresh installation of ADT.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following dependency to your Gradle build file:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.2+'
}
```

You'll need to install the "Google Repository" from the Android SDK manager.

See [`demo/build.gradle`](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/build.gradle) for an example.

You can, of course, copy the `library` directory and use it like any other Android library project.

Let me know if this helps!

Chris

Comment: I can not use com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.1+ at my project

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. First File>Project Structure>Click Plus Button >Import Graddle Project>Select the file(library folder) from the location where downloaded>CLick Ok.
2. Add this code to dependencies to that app module build.gradle file(remember there are two build.gradle files) :

   dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
   }
3. Copy gradle.properties file contents of that Android-maps-util Library project app(found inside that project library folder) TO 
   gradle.properties file of your project(Simple copy and paste of content to the editor).
4. Click Sync Project with gradle files button. And you must be fine!